# Static context menu command target

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have the following context menu on the header of a column in a datagridview.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Include,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Width="50">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Export">
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Alle auswaehlen"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Alle abwahelen"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>      
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

As you can see, the context menu is static. How can I map the `Command` attribute to static methods in my code? All examples I found online were for flexible binding or for cut/copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the click event instead:

```
<MenuItem Header="Alle auswaehlen" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
```

And then have this method in your code:

```
private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why that `ContextMenu` would be static; it appears to be created for each text block, which will be created for each header. If you only have one header, then I suppose it's *de facto* static.

Either way, if you want to bind to static command `MyCommand` of class `MyNamespace.MyClass`, then you use the following syntax:

```
<MenuItem Header="header" Command="{x:Static mynamespace:MyClass.MyCommand}"/>
```

Note that you need to have specified the xml namespace on the parent XAML object as follows:

```
xmlns:mynamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
```

Comment: How would the `MyClass` need to look? I find all the command examples on the internet quite confusing...